# $f(2^k)$ divides $f(2^{k+1})$

Tags: contest-math, solution-verification

**Problem:**
For any integer $d > 0,$ let $f(d)$ be the smallest possible integer that has exactly $d$ positive divisors (so for example we have $f(1)=1, f(5)=16,$ and $f(6)=12$). Prove that for every integer $k \geq 0$ the number $f\left(2^k\right)$ divides $f\left(2^{k+1}\right).$

Proposed by Suhaimi Ramly, Malaysia

**Source:** IMO Shortlist 2011, Number Theory 1

**My solution:**

It's trivial that the number $f\left(2^k\right)$ is in the form $p_1^{2^{a_1} -1}p_2^{2^{a_2} -1}...p_n^{2^{a_n} -1}$. And $2^{a_1}2^{a_2}...2^{a_n}=2^k$. Assume we have the smallest integer $f\left(2^k\right)$. In order to get number $2^{k+1}$, we have to either multiply $f\left(2^k\right)$ by some new prime number or change and exponent $2^{a_i}-1$ to $2^{a_i+1}-1$. Hence $f\left(2^k\right)$ always divides $f\left(2^{k+1}\right)$.

**Note:** The solution other students proposed were really complicated, I was wondering where the mistake in my solution is?

Comment: You’re not treating the case where you decide to “sacrifice” some powers of prime factors (say, the larger ones) to “boost” the smaller ones (eg you diminish $a_n$ by $1$ and add $2$ to $a_1$). Nor are you addressing more complicated schemes for changing the exponents.

Comment: It turns out that $\frac{f\left(2^{n+1}\right)}{f\left(2^{n}\right)}$ is a number of the form $p^{2^k}$ for some prime $p$ and integer $k$, using the smallest such new numbers first. So your explantation is correct.  Whether it is a proof is a slightly  different question and you may need to explain why @Mindlack's case does not in fact produce a smaller number

Comment: To illustrate the difficulty: if the question had been *"Prove that for every integer $k \geq 0$ the number $f\left(k\right)$ divides $f\left(2k\right)$"* you might have tried something similar but it would have been wrong as $f(810)=277477200$ does not divide $f(1620)=3632428800$ (a nice delayed counter example)